# Showing that $\lim\limits_{{x\to 1}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}\right)^2\right]$, $x\neq -1$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

This problem seems too difficult for me to solve. Hence, I need the help of those in the house by providing me a detailed solution. The question actually requires me to show that if $$f(x)=\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}\right)^2,\quad x\neq -1,$$ then I should find $\lim\limits_{{x\to 1}}f(x)$.

Is it also possible to redefine $f(-1)$ in such a way that $f$ is continuous at $-1$?

Comment: Forget about $-1.$ It suffices to know what $f(x)$ is for  $x$ in a small interval centered at $1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that $x>1$ if $x\to1^+$, one has
$$\lim\limits_{{x\to 1^+}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}\right)^2\right]=\lim\limits_{{x\to 1^+}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{x^n}}{1+\frac{1}{x^n}}\right)^2\right]=\lim\limits_{{x\to 1^+}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{1-0}{1+0}\right)^2\right]=1.$$
Also noting that $x<1$ if $x\to1^-$, one can choose $0<x<1$ and  one has
$$\lim\limits_{{x\to 1^-}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}\right)^2\right]=\lim\limits_{{x\to 1^+}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{0-1}{0+1}\right)^2\right]=1.$$
So
$$ \lim\limits_{{x\to 1^-}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}\right)^2\right]=\lim\limits_{{x\to 1^+}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}\right)^2\right]=1 $$
which implies
$$ \lim\limits_{{x\to 1}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}\right)^2\right]=1 $$
exists.

Comment: @ xpaul: Thanks a lot! What if I want to find $\lim\limits_{{x\to -1}}\left[\lim\limits_{{n\to\infty}}\left(\frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1}\right)^2\right]$, $x\neq -1$? Should I also include it in the above question?

Comment: @Mike, for $x=-1$, you can use the perfect square formula first and then use the same way to treat the limit.

Comment: @ xpaul:Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The inner fraction tends to $1$ for $x>1$ and to $-1$ for $0<x<1$. Then after squaring, the limit to $x\to1$ is $1$.

The behavior is quite similar around $x=-1$, despite the alternating sign. So $f(-1):=1$.

Comment: If $-1<x<0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = 0$ , so $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x^n-1)/(x^n+1) = (-1)/(1) = -1$ . Right?

Comment: And if $x<-1$, then $-1<\frac1x<0$ , so $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^n-1}{x^n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-(1/x)^n}{1+(1/x)^n} = \frac11 = 1$ .

Comment: @mr_e_man: you are quite right, fixing.

Answer (score 0):

What if we take $x^{2n}$ common from both numerator and denominator, cancel each out. That leads numerator to $$1-\frac{1}{x^n}$$ and denominator to $$1+\frac{1}{x^n}$$ on which, when limits are applied become, $$\frac{1 - 0}{1+0} = 1 = f(x).$$

Comment: A constant function is not continuous where it's not defined.

Comment: ohh yes, my bad. Thanks.